# Почему приложение Kivy выходит из строя на моем телефоне при использовании boto3, paramiko?

Tags: python, kivy, apk, paramiko, ec2

У меня есть небольшое приложение, которое отправляет команду в AWS EC2 и запускает там скрипт. Создавал приложения на виртуальной машине Xubuntu с использованием python 3.6. На Windows все работает нормально. Мне также удалось построить другие приложения с Kivy и KivyMD на этой виртуальной машине. При использовании кода и зависимостей ниже мое приложение успешно строится, но когда я нажимаю на значок приложения на своем смартфоне, оно вылетает.

Вот часть моего spec файла.

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
requirements = kivy==1.11.1, kivymd, boto3, botocore, openssl, paramiko, urllib3, s3transfer, ecdsa
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

И сам код программы:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import kivy
import boto3
import paramiko
import io
kivy.require('1.11.1')

KV = '''
Screen:
    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        id: button
        text: "Start"
        font_size: "18sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.15}
        on_release: app.start()

'''

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def start(self):
        def lambda_handler():

            client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key,
                                  region_name='us-east-2')

        describeInstance = client.describe_instances()

        private_key_file = io.StringIO()
        private_key_file.write('key')
        private_key_file.seek(0)
        # reading pem file and creating key object
        key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(private_key_file)

            ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()

            ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

            ssh_client.connect(hostname="18.18.18.18", username="ubuntu", pkey=key)

            commands = [
                "python3 /home/ubuntu/server.py 'text'",
            ]

            print("Starting execution")
            for command in commands:
                print("Executing command: " + command)
                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
                print(stdout.read())
                print(stderr.read())

            print("finished execution")

        lambda_handler()

MainApp().run()
```

[log файл](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-KQA2QTSse3oQuybDqRIRts6Cva9Dc9f/view)

Comment: По ссылке на диск: "Нет доступа". Скиньте лог лучше на https://pastebin.com или https://gist.github.com

Comment: Поправил) Доступ по ссылке был отключен